# vim - latex suite compile and view keys does not work

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I'm trying to setup vim-LaTeX on a new pc and I'm having problems with compile and view. (
`\ll` and `\lv` commands).

When I push `\ll` I get the following error;

```
Error detected while processing function Tex_RunLaTeX..Tex_SetupErrorWindow..Tex_GetMainFileName:
line   23:
E121: Undefined variable: v:true
E116: Invalid arguments for function glob('*.latexmain',v:true) == ''
E15: Invalid expression: glob('*.latexmain',v:true) == ''
line   34:
E121: Undefined variable: v:true
E116: Invalid arguments for function glob('*.latexmain',v:true)
E15: Invalid expression: glob('*.latexmain',v:true)
line   35:
E121: Undefined variable: lheadfile
E15: Invalid expression: lheadfile != ''
line   51:
E121: Undefined variable: lheadfile
E15: Invalid expression: lheadfile
```

When i try to `\lv` I get don't get an error, but evince does not open either.

Comment: update your vim

Comment: I think it should be updated (I'm on a redhat enterprise machine, but sadly I have no sudo rights over it) The machine does however update every now and then

Comment: unfortunately, the version distributed with your RHEL might not be new enough for many plugins.  You could try the plugin https://github.com/lervag/vimtex instead, which aims to support vim 7.4 and above.  But no guarantees.  If this all fails you could build vim from source in your home directory (no su needed).

Comment: I would really like to have the `latex-suite` as I'm used to it (and i lack some library to install from source). But I think the problem might be simpler, EVERYTHING not a `\` command from the `latex-suite` seems to work fine

Comment: Well, you could always ask on the latex-suite/vim-latex issue tracker (which one you are using is unclear).  It looks like an easy fix (`v:true` isn't available on your vim version).